# iphone how to grab first letter of last name for group section tableview using sqlite?

Tags: iphone, ios, header, tableview

I would like to know how to make a alphabet group sections for the names extracted from sqlite database in iphone (xcode 4.2). I was able to do group section for first name but was unable to do the last name part. Some name have lowercase I want the headers letter to have all capital which includes the lower and uppercase letters of those names. Some names have 3 names and wanted to make sure i get the last name. My code is below and it seems to mix up the alphabet (from A to L to C to D) and also e and E (lower and upper which i dont want to display)

> //---create the index---
>
> nameIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> ```
> for (int i=0; i<[_authorsInfo count]-1; i++){
>     //---get the first char of each state---
>     authors *tempAuthor = [_authorsInfo objectAtIndex:i];
>     char alphabet = [tempAuthor.name characterAtIndex:0];
>     NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
>
>     //---add each letter to the index array---
>     if (![nameIndex containsObject:uniChar])
>     {            
>         [nameIndex addObject:uniChar];
>     }
> ```

UPDATE*

> self.authorsInfo = [poemDatabase database].authorsInfo;
>
> ```
> //---create the index---
> nameIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> for (int i=0; i<[_authorsInfo count]-1; i++){
>     //---get the first char of each state---
>     authors *tempAuthor = [_authorsInfo objectAtIndex:i];
>     NSArray *nameComponents = [tempAuthor.name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
>     NSString *lastName = [ nameComponents objectAtIndex: nameComponents.count-1 ];
>     char alphabet = [lastName characterAtIndex:0];
>
>
>     //char alphabet = [tempAuthor.name characterAtIndex:0];
>     NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
>
>     //---add each letter to the index array---
>     if (![nameIndex containsObject:uniChar])
>     {            
>         [nameIndex addObject:uniChar];
>     }        
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tempAuthor.name` contains whole name with spaces try this:

```
NSArray *nameComponents = [tempAuthor.name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *lastName = [ nameComponents objectAtIndex: nameComponents.count-1 ]
char alphabet = [lastName characterAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: it shows up in random letters not in order and also its not getting the last name as I posted the update code Thanks